# Why is in my tomcat application too many open files after request is over?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have Tomcat application which is monitoring by Grafana. Strange think in this application is there are too many open files and its there for 30 mins, after I hit endpoint. Can someone give me a point how to decrease open files when my request is over? Thank you[image]

Comment: Run **SonarLint** or an other code checker over your software. When a `close` was forgotten / skipped by exception,, use try-with-resources. That is a pro-active way of dealing with leakage.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of explanations for this:

1. The file descriptors could be sockets associated with long-lived websockets.
2. They could be database connections that are being kept open by a JDBC connection pool.
3. Your application code code could be leaking open files, sockets, JDBC or HTTPClient connections or something like that.  These will stay open until the GC runs and finds that they are unreachable.  When they are (eventually) collected, the file descriptors will be closed.

The solution will depend on the cause.  For example if you are leaking open files or JDBC connections, the solution will be to use *try with resources* to ensure that the files / connections are *always* closed.